# HTTrack Empty Mirror Error

Tags: download, website, mirroring, httrack

I'm trying to download the following site: http://www.interneto-parduotuve.lt/

However, no matter what I try to do (get rid of the www, try other options than the "download website" one, etc) I keep getting a "HTTrack has detected that the current mirror is empty." error. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was apparently using an older version of Mozilla as the browser within HTTrack. I changed the version to 4.0 and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I hate to kick up old threads, but I have run into the same problem.

HTTrack version: 3.48-19

My solution was to use the browser identity of:

HyperBrowser (Cray;I;OrganicOS 9.7.42beta-27)

I have never used this identity before, but it has definitely started the mirror.

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution was to use a current and existing User-Agent. I retrieved the one of my real browser by visiting https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent

Answer (score 0):

This tools will only work based on links between the pages. If a page has no other pages pointing to it, it's *invisible* for HTTrack (and other *spider* tools). If you know the URLs to this *unlinked* pages, you add them manually.